# Dining philosophers's problem with test-set instruction

Tags: c, operating-system, pseudocode

having test-set instruction defined as:

```
  function TestAndSet (var x: boolean): boolean;
  begin
    TestAndSet = x;
    x = true
  end;
```

is it possible to solve dining philosophers's problem ? And yes, I know that we can solve it using semaphores or monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, an *atomic* `TestAndSet` is enough to make a mutex lock.  `TestAndSet(fork)` is an attempted lock that returns `false` if it's successful.  `fork=false` unlocks it.

You can use Dijkstra's solution -- every philosopher locks the northernmost fork first.

Comment: Dijkstra's solution is "unfair" - one philosopher can be very lucky and always eat while another philosopher can be very unlucky and starve.

Comment: Yes, it is... but it's still the most common (and usually simplest) way to avoid deadlock in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For one example; with an atomic `TestAndSet` instruction and an atomic `clear` instruction; it's possible to nominate a "controlling philosopher" in a fair manner; where the nominated controlling philosopher checks if both of their forks are free and decides if they can/can't eat, and then releases control.

For example:

```
while(running) {
    if(testAndSet(controllerFlag) == TRUE) {
        if(nextController == ME) {
            if(bothForksAreFree()) {
                myNextState = EATING;
                markBothForksInUse(ME);
            } else {
                myNextState = WAITING;
            }
            nextController = nextController + 1;
            if(nextController > MAX_CONTROLLERS) {
                nextController = 0;
            }
        }
        clear(controllerFlag);
        if(myNextState == EATING) {
            eat();
            markBothForksFree(ME);
            think();
        }
    }
}
```

For data; this involves assigning each philosopher a unique and sequential number (e.g. 0 to N), the `controllerFlag`, plus a flag to represent the state of each fork (in use, free). The `markBothForksFree()` may need to use the "atomic clear" instruction, but everything else is guarded by `controllerFlag`.

Comment: The algorithm makes no progress until the current 'next controller' wants to eat.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: That's what makes it fair. Of course if a philosopher isn't hungry they can `eat()` for zero time, and to improve performance "thinking" can be split into many periods between "zero time eating".

Comment: "fair" in a "sucks for everybody" kind of way ;-)

Comment: @MattTimmermans: Well, "fair" in the "everyone has an equal chance to eat" way (or maybe in a "sucks for gluttons" way).